# Why the map/reduce output a empty file, with no exception reported

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I implemented a simple map/reduce program to make a inverted-sort index(a part of my small search engine). Every thing worked just fine. But after I enlarged the input file size to more than 20MB(still small file for test), The output file will be empty. It means that I can find the file 'part-00000', but it's 0 bytes.

The strange part is there is no exception at all.
Here' s my log:

(Notice that 'Map input records=19405, Combine output records=4111513, Reduce input records=0')

```
SEInvertedIndex Program starts!...
12/10/28 00:58:05 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
12/10/28 00:58:05 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
12/10/28 00:58:05 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
12/10/28 00:58:05 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
12/10/28 00:58:05 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
12/10/28 00:58:05 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
12/10/28 00:58:05 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
12/10/28 00:58:05 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@8c4a77
12/10/28 00:58:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
12/10/28 00:58:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
12/10/28 00:58:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
12/10/28 00:58:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
12/10/28 00:58:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:08 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:08 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 25657705; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:58:08 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 0; kvend = 262144; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:10 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
12/10/28 00:58:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 25657705; bufend = 55385370; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:58:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 262144; kvend = 196607; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:11 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:58:12 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 5% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 1
12/10/28 00:58:13 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:13 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 55385370; bufend = 87701074; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:58:13 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 196607; kvend = 131070; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:14 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:58:14 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 2
12/10/28 00:58:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 8% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 87701074; bufend = 17642207; bufvoid = 99614622
12/10/28 00:58:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 131070; kvend = 65533; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:17 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 3
12/10/28 00:58:17 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:58:17 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:17 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 17642207; bufend = 47171716; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:58:17 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 65533; kvend = 327677; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 12% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:19 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 4
12/10/28 00:58:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 47171716; bufend = 75047441; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:58:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 327677; kvend = 262140; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:58:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 16% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:21 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 5
12/10/28 00:58:22 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:22 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 75047441; bufend = 7640048; bufvoid = 99614657
12/10/28 00:58:22 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 262140; kvend = 196603; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:23 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:58:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 6
12/10/28 00:58:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 19% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 7640048; bufend = 39737149; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:58:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 196603; kvend = 131066; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:26 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 7
12/10/28 00:58:26 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:58:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 39737149; bufend = 69183305; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:58:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 131066; kvend = 65529; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:27 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 21% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:28 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 8
12/10/28 00:58:29 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:29 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 69183305; bufend = 97875327; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:58:29 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 65529; kvend = 327673; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:29 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:58:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 26% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 9
12/10/28 00:58:32 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:32 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 97875327; bufend = 31087133; bufvoid = 99614698
12/10/28 00:58:32 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 327673; kvend = 262136; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:32 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:58:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 29% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:33 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 10
12/10/28 00:58:34 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:34 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 31087133; bufend = 62067679; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:58:34 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 262136; kvend = 196599; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:35 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:58:36 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 11
12/10/28 00:58:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 31% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:36 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:36 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 62067679; bufend = 96839215; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:58:36 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 196599; kvend = 131062; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:38 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 12
12/10/28 00:58:38 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:58:39 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:39 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 96839215; bufend = 29204841; bufvoid = 99614697
12/10/28 00:58:39 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 131062; kvend = 65525; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 36% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:40 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 13
12/10/28 00:58:41 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:41 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 29204841; bufend = 59391566; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:58:41 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 65525; kvend = 327669; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:41 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:58:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 39% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:42 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 14
12/10/28 00:58:43 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:43 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 59391566; bufend = 88629854; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:58:43 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 327669; kvend = 262132; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:44 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:58:45 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 15
12/10/28 00:58:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 42% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:46 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:46 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 88629854; bufend = 19479345; bufvoid = 99614663
12/10/28 00:58:46 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 262132; kvend = 196595; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:47 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 16
12/10/28 00:58:47 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:58:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 45% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:48 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:48 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 19479345; bufend = 50425350; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:58:48 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 196595; kvend = 131058; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:50 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 17
12/10/28 00:58:50 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:58:50 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:50 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 50425350; bufend = 81295514; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:58:50 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 131058; kvend = 65521; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 49% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:52 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 18
12/10/28 00:58:53 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:53 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 81295514; bufend = 10297619; bufvoid = 99614693
12/10/28 00:58:53 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 65521; kvend = 327665; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:53 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:58:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 53% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:54 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 19
12/10/28 00:58:55 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:55 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 10297619; bufend = 40501081; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:58:55 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 327665; kvend = 262128; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:56 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:58:57 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 20
12/10/28 00:58:57 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 55% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:58:57 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:58:57 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 40501081; bufend = 70713611; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:58:57 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 262128; kvend = 196591; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:58:59 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 21
12/10/28 00:58:59 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:59:00 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:59:00 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 70713611; bufend = 3303900; bufvoid = 99614652
12/10/28 00:59:00 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 196591; kvend = 131054; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:59:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 59% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:59:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 22
12/10/28 00:59:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:59:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 3303900; bufend = 34088069; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:59:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 131054; kvend = 65517; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:59:02 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:59:03 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 63% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:59:04 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 23
12/10/28 00:59:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:59:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 34088069; bufend = 63394277; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:59:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 65517; kvend = 327661; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:59:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:59:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 66% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:59:06 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 24
12/10/28 00:59:07 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:59:07 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 63394277; bufend = 94566907; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:59:07 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 327661; kvend = 262124; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:59:08 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 25
12/10/28 00:59:08 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:59:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 70% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:59:09 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:59:09 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 94566907; bufend = 29503862; bufvoid = 99614698
12/10/28 00:59:09 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 262124; kvend = 196587; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:59:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 26
12/10/28 00:59:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:59:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:59:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 29503862; bufend = 63726597; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:59:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 196587; kvend = 131050; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:59:12 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 73% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:59:14 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 27
12/10/28 00:59:14 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:59:14 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 63726597; bufend = 99242470; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:59:14 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 131050; kvend = 65513; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:59:15 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:59:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 77% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:59:16 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 28
12/10/28 00:59:17 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:59:17 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 99242470; bufend = 35558411; bufvoid = 99614660
12/10/28 00:59:17 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 65513; kvend = 327657; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:59:18 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:59:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 80% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:59:18 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 29
12/10/28 00:59:19 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:59:19 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 35558411; bufend = 70034163; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:59:19 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 327657; kvend = 262120; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:59:21 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 30
12/10/28 00:59:21 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:59:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 83% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:59:21 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:59:21 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 70034163; bufend = 4759655; bufvoid = 99614713
12/10/28 00:59:21 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 262120; kvend = 196583; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:59:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 31
12/10/28 00:59:24 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:59:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 85% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:59:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:59:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 4759655; bufend = 39709563; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:59:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 196583; kvend = 131046; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:59:26 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 32
12/10/28 00:59:27 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:59:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:59:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 39709563; bufend = 74269540; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:59:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 131046; kvend = 65509; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:59:27 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 89% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:59:29 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 33
12/10/28 00:59:29 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:59:29 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 74269540; bufend = 9768351; bufvoid = 99614650
12/10/28 00:59:29 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 65509; kvend = 327653; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:59:30 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:59:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 93% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:59:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 34
12/10/28 00:59:32 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:59:32 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 9768351; bufend = 43640794; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:59:32 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 327653; kvend = 262116; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:59:33 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:59:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 96% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:59:33 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 35
12/10/28 00:59:34 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
12/10/28 00:59:34 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 43640794; bufend = 77787072; bufvoid = 99614720
12/10/28 00:59:34 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 262116; kvend = 196579; length = 327680
12/10/28 00:59:36 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 36
12/10/28 00:59:36 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:59:36 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
12/10/28 00:59:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 99% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:59:37 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 37
12/10/28 00:59:37 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 38 sorted segments
12/10/28 00:59:37 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 2 intermediate segments out of a total of 38
12/10/28 00:59:38 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 10 intermediate segments out of a total of 37
12/10/28 00:59:39 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:59:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
12/10/28 00:59:42 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 00:59:45 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 01:00:21 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 10 intermediate segments out of a total of 28
12/10/28 01:00:24 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 01:00:27 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 01:00:28 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 10 intermediate segments out of a total of 19
12/10/28 01:00:30 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 01:00:33 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 01:00:35 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 10 segments left of total size: 512806627 bytes
12/10/28 01:00:36 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 01:00:39 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
12/10/28 01:00:39 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 01:00:39 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webData/data12.out:0+66123962
12/10/28 01:00:39 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0' done.
12/10/28 01:00:39 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@61f533
12/10/28 01:00:39 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
12/10/28 01:00:39 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
12/10/28 01:00:39 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 0 segments left of total size: 0 bytes
12/10/28 01:00:39 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
12/10/28 01:00:39 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
12/10/28 01:00:39 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
12/10/28 01:00:39 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
12/10/28 01:00:39 INFO mapred.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0' to hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/webDataOut
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0' done.
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 22
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=66123962
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=0
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=1866062016
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=132247924
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=1866142216
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=6
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=19405
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=7484422
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=1192717378
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=845938688
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=0
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input bytes=66123962
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=105
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=13954115
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=0
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=0
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=4111513
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=0
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
12/10/28 01:00:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=9842602
SEInvertedIndex Program ends!...
```

My implementation is really simple, and it worked just fine when the input file is small.
Thx a lot!

Here' s the code:

```
package com.zhoutall.SEInvertedIndex;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat;
import org.wltea.analyzer.core.IKSegmenter;
import org.wltea.analyzer.core.Lexeme;

public class SEInvertedIndex {


    public static class InvertedIndexMapper extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
        private final static Text One = new Text("1");

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text val,
                OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {

            String strContent_all=new String(val.getBytes(), 0, val.getLength(), "utf-8");
            if(strContent_all==null || strContent_all=="\n")
                return;
//          System.out.println(strContent_all);
            String strUrl=null;
            String strContent = null;
            String strPart[] = strContent_all.split("   ");
//          if(strPart.length!=2)
//              return;
            strUrl = strPart[0].replace("http", "https");
            strContent = strPart[1];
            //System.out.println(strUrl+"~~"+strContent);

            String webHead = new String(strContent.substring(0, 20) + "...").replace("&nbsp;", " ");
            StringReader strReader = new StringReader(strContent);
            IKSegmenter ik = new IKSegmenter(strReader, true);
            Lexeme lexeme = null;
            while ((lexeme = ik.next()) != null) {
                // System.out.println(lexeme.getLexemeText() + "##" + strUrl + "##" + webHead);
                output.collect(new Text(lexeme.getLexemeText() + "##" + strUrl + "##" + webHead), One);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class InvertedIndexCombiner extends MapReduceBase implements
            Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
                OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {
            int sum = 0;
            while (values.hasNext()) {
                values.next();
                sum += 1;
            }
//          System.out.println(key.toString());
            String fields[] = key.toString().split("##");
            if(fields.length!=3)
                return;
//          System.out.println(fields[1]+"##"+fields[2] + "##" + sum);
            output.collect(new Text(fields[0]), new Text(fields[1] + "##" + fields[2] + "##" + sum));
        }
    }

    public static class InvertedIndexReducer extends MapReduceBase implements
            Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
                OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {

            boolean first = true;
            StringBuilder count_all = new StringBuilder();

            while (values.hasNext()) {
                if (!first)
                    count_all.append(";;");
                first = false;
                count_all.append(values.next().toString());
            }
//          System.out.println(key+"::"+count_all.toString());
            output.collect(key, new Text(count_all.toString()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("SEInvertedIndex Program starts!...");
        JobClient client = new JobClient();
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(SEInvertedIndex.class);

        conf.setJobName("SEInvertedIndex");

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        //conf.setNumReduceTasks(1);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
        // ////////////////
        Path dstFilePath = new Path(args[1]);
        FileSystem fs = null;
        try {
            fs = dstFilePath.getFileSystem(conf);
            if (fs.exists(dstFilePath))
                fs.delete(dstFilePath, true);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        // /////////////////
        conf.setMapperClass(InvertedIndexMapper.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(InvertedIndexCombiner.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(InvertedIndexReducer.class);

        client.setConf(conf);

        try {
            JobClient.runJob(conf);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("SEInvertedIndex Program ends!...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a problem in your combiner implementation.

From the counters it you can see something is wrong:

```
Combine input records=13954115
Reduce input records=0
Reduce input groups=0
Combine output records=4111513
```

This breakdown doesn't show you, but the combiner runs both map side, and reduce side - the job tracker web UI page should give you the complete breakdown.

Anyway the combiner map side alters the key, which when if it passes through a combiner again (map or reduce side) is being rejected by the field length != 3 condition:

```
if(fields.length!=3)
    return;
output.collect(new Text(fields[0]), new Text(fields[1] + "##" + fields[2] + "##" + sum));
```

So here you're amending the input key and outputting field[0] as the key (and the value looks like what you should be outputting as the key - it has 3 fields ## separated), now if this data is feed through a combiner map side again(which is possible), it will be rejected. Any data that is output from the map side combiner will be rejected reduce side as the key now does contain 3 ## delimited fields anymore.

Unrelated to your problem byt you also might want to look through some other portions of your code (in the mapper for example):

```
String strContent_all=new String(val.getBytes(), 0, val.getLength(), "utf-8");
if(strContent_all==null || strContent_all=="\n")
    return;
```

This condition will never fire true as strContent will never be null, and you should be `using strContent_all.equals("\n")` rather than `==` which is testing reference equality.

Comment: It is the combiner that causes the problem. I split it into two map/reduce process.The combiner is used as the first reducer. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The log shows a huge number of map records written but 0 (zero) reduce records read in.

If I had to guess, the records are getting lost in the regex expression "##" you're using to split the records in the combiner.  The "#" is used as a comment in regex and so you might not be splitting the records like you think you are.  Your logic shows that if you don't split into 3 substrings then nothing is written out.

Try using:

```
String fields[] = key.toString().split("\\#\\#");
```

This escapes the "#"'s.

btw.  I make it a practice to try to factor the logic out of the map() and reduce() methods so I can hit it with JUnit tests.  I also try to use counters to indicate when and where I'm returning out of these methods.  Those practices are very good, if I say so myself, and they'll help resolve problems like this (even if I'm totally wrong about why the code's not working:)

Comment: "##" is ok. The problem is about combiner.Thx~